# Is there a way to override js object property retrieval?

Tags: javascript

I need to analyze functions automatically and determine which properties of an object are used by each function.

The functions are very simple, for example

```
(a, b) => Math.min(100, 50 + a.strength, 50 + b.strength)
```

all of the properties of the input objects are numeric and the functions make no changes to the input objects

My first thought was to analyze the string form of the function but to make it more foolproof, it would be perfect if I could run each of the functions with test dummy objects that dynamically deliver a requested property of any name and make a note of that name.

In vb.net for example, you can define a default property for classes so that each object(key) access can be dynamically handled based on the key value. Is there something similar in js?

Comment: Not clear what kind of result you are supposed to produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and pass them to the function, and log which properties were called:

```js
const fn = (a, b) => Math.min(100, 50 + a.strength, 50 + b.strength)

var aProxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (obj, prop) => console.log(`${prop} was called on a`)
});

var bProxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (obj, prop) => console.log(`${prop} was called on b`)
});

fn(aProxy, bProxy);
```

Comment: that's exactly what i needed